# Regex for location matching - Python

Tags: python, regex

How would you match locations (Places) with regular expressions in python. It should match locations of the following format:

- **London, ENG, United Kingdom**
- **Melbourne, VIC, Australia**
- **Palo Alto, CA USA**

I've tried this but it doesnt work:

```
re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]+ ([A-Z][a-z]+)?,)+',x)
```

EDIT:

okay, let me make it clear what i want. i have a huge wall of text. i need to detect locations like the above mentioned from the text. not validate.

Example:

```
text = """
..............................
..............................
London, ENG, United Kingdom...
..............................
"""
re.findall(r'<something>',x)
#['London, ENG, United Kingdom']
```

it should be able to match any location of the format `Xxxx, XXX, Xxxx` with optional commas and optionally multiple words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)?

```
'London, ENG, United Kingdom or Melbourne, VIC, Australia or Palo Alto, CA USA'
>>> list(map(str.strip, re.split(',|or', x)))
['London', 'ENG', 'United Kingdom', 'Melbourne', 'VIC', 'Australia', 'Palo Alto', 'CA USA']
>>> list(map(str.strip, re.split('or', x)))
['London, ENG, United Kingdom', 'Melbourne, VIC, Australia', 'Palo Alto, CA USA']
```

---

If you want location to be splitted with `or`, you don't need to use regular expression. Just use `str.split`:

```
>>> list(map(str.strip, x.split('or')))
['London, ENG, United Kingdom', 'Melbourne, VIC, Australia', 'Palo Alto, CA USA']
```

- `list` is not needed if you use Python 2.x.

---

**UPDATE**

```
>>> x = 'London, ENG, United Kingdom / Melbourne, VIC, Australia / Palo Alto, CA USA'
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\w+(?:\s+\w+)*,\s)+(?:\w+(?:\s\w+)*)', x)
['London, ENG, United Kingdom', 'Melbourne, VIC, Australia', 'Palo Alto, CA USA']
```

Comment: the "or" was just to separate the examples..!

Comment: those were just examples i gave. i need to match locations with _that_ format in a huge wall of text..

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi, not perfect...  You need to remove unnecessary word like `or` yourself.

Comment: or is just to "separate" the example i gave!!

Comment: hey, there's a problem: `x ="Melbourne, VIC, Australia London, ENG, United Kingdom"` when i run your code, it returns: `['Melbourne, VIC, Australia London', 'ENG, United Kingdom']` instead of `['Melbourne, VIC, Australia', 'London, 'ENG, United Kingdom']`

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi, Is it okay to predefine know countries? (like `countries = 'Australia', 'United Kingdom', 'USA'`). Without it, it's impossible as far as I know to give you what you want.

Comment: no.. what i can understand is your regex is trying to match `xxx, xxx, xxx xxx` i need it to match `xxx+, xxx+, xxx+` with _optionally_ multiple words

Comment: i mean `xxx (one or more), xxx(one or more), xxx(one or more)`

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi, I updated the answer. `\w+` only match single word. The pattern in your answer does not match what you want. For example, for `'London, ENG, United Kingdom'`, it only match `'London, ENG, United'`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use (expensive) regex when you can do it much more efficiently using a dictionary:

```
locations = {"London, ENG, United Kingdom":True, "Melbourne, VIC, Australia":True...}
```

The it's easy to use `locations` to see if `x` is one of them.

**Update (after the edit):**
Still, there's no need to use (expensive) regex since you're not doing any kind of pattern matching. You're preforming a simple substring search so use:

```
"London, ENG, United Kingdom" in text
```

or, in more general way, create a list of locations:

```
locations = ["London, ENG, United Kingdom", "Melbourne, VIC, Australia",...]
...
for location in locations:
    for location in text:
        # do what you want here
```

Comment: i dont have to match only london or melbourne or palo alto, any location with the format i've exampled...

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi right, so create a list of locations and do: `for location in locations: ... if location in text: ...`

Comment: i dont want to match a certain list of locations.. i want to match any location with the format i've specified after the example.. check my update

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi see update. Point is still valid - you don't do any kind of pattern matching hence - no need for regex!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i found my answer myself, its fairly simple:

```
r'\w+, \w+, \w+'
```

But to respect @falsetru's efforts i'll accept his answer.. Thankyou @falsetru